# Where are my Vista documents?

Tags: windows-vista, crash, find, my-documents

on my compputer here at work, the motherboard on one machine decided to fry over the weekend, all of my saved work is on the harddrive here, it has Vista Business as it's OS and my documents were in My Documents.

I have since moved the HDD over to a new computer and am trying to locate these files, as I can't work without them and it's not a case of doing it again, this is over three months work.

There were three user accounts, mine, my bosses and a guest accont.

Where are these My Documents?

How can I get them?

Thanks for any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Users\$username\Documents , if I remember correctly. The 'Documents and Settings' Folder is inaccessible, instead you have to use the 'Users' folder.

Comment: Thanks, turned out to be F:/Users/Myname/Desktop/Documents.